# Use glob or regex pattern for rollup.js externals

Tags: javascript, bundle, rollupjs

Is it possible to use a glob or regex pattern for the externals in my rollup config? With this config:

```
export default {
  ...
  external: [
    'prop-types',
    'react',
    'prettier/standalone',
    'prettier/parser-babylon',
    'react-syntax-highlighter/prism-light',
    'react-syntax-highlighter/languages/prism/jsx',
    'react-syntax-highlighter/styles/prism/tomorrow',
    'react-element-to-string'
  ],
  ...
};
```

I would like to do something like:

```
export default {
  ...
  external: [
    'prop-types',
    'react',
    'prettier/**',
    'react-syntax-highlighter/**',
    'react-element-to-string'
  ],
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. You can however use a function to achieve something similar:

```
export default {
  ...
  external(id) {
    return [
      'prop-types',
      'react',
      'prettier',
      'react-syntax-highlighter',
      'react-element-to-string'
    ].includes(id.split('/')[0]);
  },
  ...
};
```

You should avoid costly computations in this function as it will be called a lot (once for every import in every file to be precise).

Another option is to add the `rollup-pluginutils` package as a dependency which contains a [`createFilter` function for glob support](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-pluginutils#createfilter):

```
import { createFilter } from 'rollup-pluginutils';

const external = createFilter([
  'prop-types',
  'react',
  'prettier/**',
  'react-syntax-highlighter/**',
  'react-element-to-string'
], null, {resolve: false});
// {resolve: false} will make sure these filters are not passed to
// path.resolve first and resolved against the current working directory

export default {
  ...
  external,
  ...
};
```

Comment: The first solution does not work if the package name includes `'/'` such as those with scope.

Comment: Beware of using this, the non-accepted answer below (using regex) is the way to go now.

Answer (score 4):

Regex in `external` is also supported by rollup now, like this:

```js
export default {
  external: ['three', /three\/.*/]
}
```

This will mark `three` and `three/*` as externals, I have used in my projects, it works as expected.

Please refer https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#external for more options.